# Entity Framework Complex Type Validation (DB First)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently using Entity framework 6 to interface between the user interface and the back end database, however I have a problem with validation on fields in a complex type. I'm using the database first approach.

I created my model based on existing database, then converted fields into a complex type.

For example, user model.

```
public partial class User {
    public User() {
        this.DeliveryAddress = new Address();
        this.InvoiceAddress = new Address();
    }

    public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
    public Address InvoiceAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Complex type

```
public partial class Address {
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string TownCity { get; set; }
}
```

I mapped the table correctly in the model browser and everything is compiling. However when trying to save it throws an error that validation failed. After a bit of investigation it turns out for some reason all the complex type fields are required. Which I find strange as they are strings which can be null and even in database the fields are nullable. As a work around I created a partial class of Address with a constructor to initialize all the fields to an empty string which is a temporary work around. However this isn't ideal.

Code which saves the details. (Mvc Action)

```
public ActionResult UpdateDetails(UserDetailsViewModel info) {
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {

            var user = db.Users.Find(info.UserID);
            if (user != null) {
                user.DeliveryAddress = new Data.Address {
                    CompanyName = info.DeliveryCompanyName,
                    Address1 = info.DeliveryAddress1,
                    Address2 = info.DeliveryAddress2,
                    Firstname = info.DeliveryFirstname,
                    Postcode = info.DeliveryPostcode,
                    Surname = info.DeliverySurname,
                    TownCity = info.DeliveryCity,
                };
                user.InvoiceAddress = new Data.Address();

                if (!info.IsInvoiceAddress) {
                    user.InvoiceAddress = new Data.Address {
                        Address1 = info.InvoiceAddress1,
                        Address2 = info.InvoiceAddress2,
                        Firstname = info.InvoiceFirstname,
                        Postcode = info.InvoicePostcode,
                        Surname = info.InvoiceSurname,
                        TownCity = info.InvoiceCity,
                        CompanyName = info.InvoiceCompanyName
                    };
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Json(new { Msg = "Ok" });
        }
    } catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx) {
        foreach (var valErs in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors) {
            foreach (var valEr in valErs.ValidationErrors) {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", valEr.PropertyName, valEr.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        return Json(new { Msg = "Err" });
    } catch {
        return Json(new { Msg = "Err" });
    }

    return PartialView("UserDetailsForm", info);
}
```

Has anyone come across a similar situation? Maybe Im missing something which needs to be configured.

Comment: `user.InvoiceAddress = new Data.Address();` can be removed I cannot see any purpose for this line.

Comment: @bilpor the line was helping work around the issue as it was initializing all the fields to an empty string. Also complex types themselves cannot be null so it needs to be initialized.

Comment: in that case you should make the line I said to remove an `else` on the `if (!info.IsInvoiceAddress)` statement. However, it's not true that complex object types cannot be null. As an example take Entity Framework where you may set LazyLoading to False, your parent object is likely to have many complex types not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found a solution to my issue. In the model browser options under complex types, you can expand the complex types to reveal the fields in the complex type and in the properties of each one there is a property 'Nullable' which is set to false. I set these to true, and it now saves without issues. Im quite surprised it doesnt pick up the type and change it to allow nulls depending on the type.

[image: Visual Studio Model Browser]